# Accuracy remains zero while training LSTM in keras

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to train LSTM, but while training accuracy remains zero in each epoch.
I have transformed data to multivariate Time-series data and also shape in three-dimensional shape.
I also have normalised data using minmaxsaller.

I have tried on a number of the epoch from 5 to 50 and batch size from 25 to 200. 
I have tried data samples from 1000000 to 1000 but none is working.

Every time I am getting training accuracy zero only.

Can anyone help me in understanding it or suggest some more experiments.

Following is my network.

```
from keras.layers.core import Dense,Activation,Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Flatten

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train_values.shape[1], X_train_values.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))

model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train_values, y_train.values,epochs=25, batch_size=30, verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

me too, I'm a student from china, when I train LSTM model, the model's accuracy is very close zeros, but predicted answer and test collections is very close.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdYMZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9BlI.png)

Comment: very close to what?